# Designing a database with yearly data, updated daily

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

So I'm writing an application in C# using SQLITE that will keep track of my companies sales data. We currently track sales data 12 months (including the current one) out and track it each day. I'm planning to have the ability to compare our sales data between two points (or more) in time as well, and this is the database I've designed so far. It's comprised of two tables:

salesIndex is a table with two columns, a unique id and a text representing a timestamp. This is sort of a master table to list all the times we tracked our sales data.

salesData is a table with 7 columns, the first being the id from the previous table, the second being the sales date and the next 5 are integers describing what kind of sales (ie the quantity, etc).

The concern I have is that if we do this each day for every day it's ~133k tables a year, and we'd store data for 3 years so ~400k rows and I'd imagine that would be somewhat slow to retrieve data from. Is there a better way to design a database for this? I was thinking perhaps I should create a table each day we track our sales and that way if we wanted to look up sales for a number of days we would just query each table rather than one huge one? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you mean ~133k rows per year? :)

Comment: And re creating one table per day - I'd think that this would be problematic for all but the simplest queries (for example, "how do this January's sales compare to last?" would not be a simple query to write). Is there a reason that salesData shouldn't be a single table that you update on a daily basis?

Comment: I think your design can be greatly simplified by just having a sales table that holds only sales for the current day. Then you only add 365 1/4 rows every year, and you can quickly run a query to determine the sales for any period of time. 12 months, 6 months, a comparison of the same day this year, to the same day last year, or even a comparison of 12-month periodic sales for the past X years... Creating a new table for each day seems like overkill and will be prone to data integrity issues.

Comment: Have you investigated whether there's already a software package available that can do this for you? Tracking sales data seems like a common problem that should already plenty of solutions in the marketplace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't create that many tables. You'll not just have maintenance difficulties, you'll also hurt your performance.

Simply have a single sales table with properly identified rows (which in your case probably means adding `date` to the primary key). Assuming you used indexes correctly, performance will be good even with 400 **million** rows, let alone 400 thousand rows.

A typical index is implemented as a [B-Tree](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree), whose height (and consequently the speed) depends *logarithmically* on the number of rows. In practice, this means a properly designed index will work almost instantly even on huge amount of data.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not too familiar with the ins and outs of databases so I'm unsure of what performance is like.  I cannot use a primary key since the sales table id and date would be repeated. Let's look at 3 days for simplicities sake in how we currently store our sales data.

So if i were to store our data today I would include today, tomorrow, and the next day, and currently it would look like this in the table:

Comment: Sorry..this enter to add comment is very annoying. Basically the table would look like it does here [link]http://pastebin.com/umctwAgg. Either way the table will always be sorted by the id column since the program design will not allow for an insert anywhere other than at the end and deleting data will not occur either so from what you say I would not have to worry about performance too much, thank you sir. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd make salesData a single table and just use indexes as required if you hit performance issues (e.g. on sales date)

400,000 rows is not really that much - you're mainly using integer keys, but even if each row was 200 bytes long, that'd still only be ~75mb.

It's not totally clear what the granularity of the sales data is (i.e. what does a single row signify?) so I've made the assumption that there is a single row per sale.

The benefit of keeping it as a single sales table is that the data can be queried as per the planned usage, but you'll also be able to run queries on it which you haven't thought of yet. Engineering the database to satisfy a particular query solves the immediate technical problem but may very well come back to haunt you :)

I'd say the multiple-tables approach leans too much in the direction of catering to your current specific use-case, and I think that unless you know you'll experience cripplingly bad performance, it's better to err on the side of usefulness and flexibility.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern database systems do not have much problems with retrieving data from tables with tons of rows, as long as they are indexed properly.

There is some hardware tuning you can do. You can make sure your database files are on a raid 10 set and indexes are on a raid 0 set (i.e. very fast reads). Put plenty of memory in your database server. If you have a lot of updates have your transaction logs go to a different disk than your data files (preferably a different raid 10 or at least a raid 1).

Besides the hardware- and index tuning, if you work with a properly normalized database you should never split up tables (or even databases for that matter) just for performance reasons.

The only reason to actually do this is when you are archiving data and don't use that archived data in production but only as a read-only database. (e.g. for reporting)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: don't put the indexes on RAID 0 (stripe)!! Yes you can recreate, but its not a recommended practice if reliability is important to you (it usually is).

Comment: Ditto at what Mitch said.  When it comes to data - ALWAYS choose reliability over performance.  I would fire anyone on the spot who did this in production.

Comment: @MitchWheat I agree that reliability is mostly higher valued, although in some cases performance IS a concern. When reliability is a concern and you don't want to face downtime, indeed, stick with fault tolerance. But if performance is a concern this is still an option.

Comment: @Jeroen Landheer: It's bad advice. Don't do it.